# The SSL connection could not be established net core on IIS, but works sperately as exe

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, iis

I created an asp.net core web api in .Net Core 3.1.  It Works successfully when I debugging it using visual studio, o running it in server using exe file. But when I put web api  on IIS then service gives following error: **`One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)`**  What can be reason? how find  reason? how to solve?

Comment: Run a report to see if your IIS settings are incorrect, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: You can also use FRT to troubleshoot this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis